# Validating Python Arguments in Subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, static-typing

I'm trying to validate a few python arguments. Until we get the new static typing in Python 3.0, what is the best way of going about this.

Here is an example of what I am attempting:

```
class A(object):
    @accepts(int, int, int)
    def __init__(a, b, c):
        pass

class B(A):
    @accepts(int, int, int, int)
    def __init__(a, b, c, d):
        A.__init__(a, b, c)
```

As you can see the decorator is nicely performing type checking of the inputs to my class, but I have to define all the arguments to the second class, which gets very nasty when I have multiple levels of inheritance. I can use kwargs with some success, but it's not quite as nice as the above approach for type checking.

Essentially I want to pop one argument off the kwargs list and check it's type, then pass the remainder to it's parent, but do this in a very flexible and clean way as this scales.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define an `any` value, and decorate the subclass constructor with `@accepts(any, any, any, int)`? Your decorator won't check parameters marked with `any`, and the `@accepts` on the superclass constructor will check all the arguments passed up to it by subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to play around with the `inspect` module. It will let you enumerate superclasses, argument lists, and other fun stuff. It seems that you might want to inspect the argument list of the superclass `__init__` method and compare it against what you have in the subclass. I'm not sure if this is going to work for you or not.

I would be careful about what assumptions you make though. It might not be safe to assume that just because class A has *N* arguments to `__init__`, subclasses will contain at least *N* arguments and pass the first *N* through to the super class. If the subclass is more specific, then it might fill in all by 2 of the arguments to its superclasses `__init__` method.